# How to check to see if argv[1] ends with a particular character?

Tags: c

Im trying to figure out how to compare the `argv[1]` value with a couple of test cases. I would like to see if `argv[1]` is ending with a particular char value. So far I have the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
char strin[250];
int length;
printf("The argument supplied is %s\n", argv[1]);
strcpy(strin,argv[1]);
length = strlen(strin);
printf("Testing: %c",strin[length]);
    if( strin[length] = 'b')
    {
    printf("b in the input");
    }

}
```

But for some reason whenever I put in any input the print statement triggers. How would I check to see if the last character in the command line argument is equal to the character that I have set it equal to?

Comment: `strin[length]` -> `strin[length - 1]`

Comment: also use == instead of = in your test

Comment: assignment: `strin[length] = 'b'`; comparison: `strin[length] == 'b'`

Comment: Why you've edited away the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, all you need is to do is the following:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    // check if there's an argument to test
    if (1 > argc) {
        // extract the position of the last character
        int last_pos = strlen(argv[1])-1;
        // compare the last character with the character "b"
        if (0 <= last_pos && 'b' == argv[1][last_pos]) {
            printf("Hoora! The input ends with b!");
            return 0;
        } else {
            printf("Bummer… The input does not end with b :(");
        }
    } else {
        printf("there's no argument to test!");
    }
}
```

Now, here's a summary of what's wrong:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
char strin[250];
int length;
printf("The argument supplied is %s\n", argv[1]);

// you're doing a copy from the first argument into the
// variable strin. If argv[1] is 251 characters, you'll
// overwrite memory, and will cause a "buffer overflow".
// Whenever you need to do strcpy of data input by a user
// use strncpy().
strcpy(strin,argv[1]);

// you're extracting the /length/ of the string, not the /position/
// of the last character, so when you're trying to access at index
// length, you'll get data from one character beyond the array.
length = strlen(strin);

// so here you're seeing a random value from the memory of your computer
printf("Testing: %c",strin[length]);

// here you made a mistake and you're assigning the value 'b' to the
// value beyond the allocated memory for the array. Basically: 
// Here be dragons.

// To avoid that mistake, always put the value you're comparing against
// in a comparaison on the Left Hand Side, and the value you're comparing
// on the right hand side. Then the compiler will yell at you!
    if( strin[length] = 'b')
    {
    printf("b in the input");
    }

}
```

Comment: You forgot to check that `argv[1]` wasn't length 0 (`last_pos` might be negative).

Comment: `0 <= last_pos` ;P

Comment: But that's what I wrote 

Answer (score 1):

C arrays are zero-index based. To access the first element you do `array[0]`, to access the 10th you do `array[9]`.

```
printf("Testing: %c",strin[length]);
```

This prints out the character 1 after the last character in the string, which happens to be the null terminator `\0`. (that's how C strings work)

```
if( strin[length] = 'b')
{
  printf("b in the input");
}
```

This doesn't compare, you should use `==` instead. This also suffers from the same problem as above.

So, change your accessing to `[length - 1]` and use `==`.

Comment: On the arrays being zero-indexed: Yeah, but why would you want to check `argv[0]` for user input? Its value is determined by the launching process (ie the shell). To check _user_ provided arguments, you have to start at `argv[1]`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem That wasn't my point, my point was that the OP might've thought that [length] would point to the length'th element, which is not the case, it's  -1.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are 0-terminated and indexing begins at 0. But `strlen()` doesn't count the terminator.

So `strin[length]` is always the 0-terminator, you need `strin[length - 1]` to get the last character. And of course you can only do that if `length > 0` is true.

Comparisons in C are done using the `==` operator, the single `=` is assignment which is not what you want.

Also there's no point in copying the string, you can check in `argv[1]` directly; and `strlen()` return `size_t`, not `int`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said the last character in the string is strlen() - 1. You have another issue because you are using strcpy. If you have more than 250 characters in the argument string it is very unsafe. So you need to use strncpy for safety.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
char strin[250];
int length;
printf("The argument supplied is %s\n", argv[1]);
strncpy(strin,argv[1], 250);
length = strlen(strin);
printf("Testing: %c",strin[length-1]);
    if( strin[length] = 'b')
    {
    printf("b in the input\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: If he just wants to test the last character, there's no need to make the copy at all.

Comment: @Barmar Yes but I wanted to show him that his code is dangerous.